# Namespaces and a user-defined operators with stl algorithms

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, stl-algorithm

I was faced with incomprehensible behavior when was trying to output elements via `std::copy`. The following code is compiling and working fine.

```
namespace Foo {
  enum class Colors { green, red, blue };

  template <typename T>
  std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &_os, const T &_t) {
      _os << typename std::underlying_type<T>::type(_t);
      return _os;
  }
}

int main() {
  Foo::Colors colors[] = {Foo::Colors::red, Foo::Colors::red, Foo::Colors::blue};

  for( auto c: colors ) { std::cout << c <<std::endl; }

  std::copy(colors, colors + 4, std::ostream_iterator<Foo::Colors>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

However, if I transfer `operator <<` out of `Foo` scope, it arises problems with `std::copy`.

```
namespace Foo {
  enum class Colors { green, red, blue };
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &_os, const T &_t) {
  _os << typename std::underlying_type<T>::type(_t);
  return _os;
}

int main() {
  Foo::Colors colors[] = {Foo::Colors::red, Foo::Colors::red, Foo::Colors::blue};

  for( auto c: colors) { std::cout << c <<std::endl; } // works fine

  // arising compiler error
  std::copy(colors, colors + 4, std::ostream_iterator<Foo::Colors>(std::cout, " ")); 

  // do not help, too
  {
    using namespace Foo;
    std::copy(colors, colors + 4, std::ostream_iterator<Colors>(std::cout, " ")); 
  }
}
```

What is the reason of this behavior, and what is right way to work around?

Answer (score 4):

Your template is accepting everything and will result in ambiguity:

A smaller test case:

```
#include <iostream>

// error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << '\012'’
template <typename T>
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &_os, const T &_t) {
  _os << typename std::underlying_type<T>::type(_t);
  return _os;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Having only one and only one (!) operator << in your namespace will resolve it due to ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup)

Comment: That's true, but I think it's not the OP's problem. When you paste the OP's second code snippet into some compiler, the error is not an ambiguous function call, but that no viable overload could be found (or, "invalid operands to binary expression").

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `std::ostream_iterator<Foo::Colors>` searches for an `operator<<` while itself being in namespace `std`. The usual *unqualified lookup* will find only functions in the nearest enclosing class or namespace that contains functions with that name. For example:

```
void meow(int);
namespace foo
{
    void meow(double);

    void find_kitten()
    {
        meow(42); // calls `foo::meow(double)`
    }
}
```

The same is happening for `operator<<`. There are overloads of this operator in namespace `std`, hence, the unqualified name lookup stops and doesn't search the global namespace.

However, argument-dependent lookup always takes place for operators. It will find your function template if it's in an associated namespace of one of the argument types. This is the case in your first, but not in your second example.

---

Side remark:

Please compile with warnings, you function template is missing a return value:

```
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &_os, const T &_t) {
  _os << typename std::underlying_type<T>::type(_t);
  return _os; // <--- missing
}
```